# jquery Getting rid of dotted outline around buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get rid of the dotted outline that appears in FF when you click an input of type button. This outline doesn't appear in Chrome.

I've tried:

```
.button {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
.button:active {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
.button:focus {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

None of these work. Anyone know the real solution? Thanks.

Edit: Looking for a better solution.

onclick flashes the outline, as in, it appears, and then disappears on mouseup. I tried binding the blur to mousedown and mouseup, but the flash persists.

Anyone have any better ideas?

Thanks.

Edit again:

Solution works in latest version of FF. Looks like a bug was fixed or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you could try adding a blur() event:

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="this.blur()" />
```

Comment: You should not use obtrusive event handlers like this.

Answer (score 3):

The dotted outline is Firefox's way of indicating to the user what element has focus.  If you're writing some sort of client application where buttons/links/elements are clicked and that DOM isn't changed, then you will see FF's focus outline.  The only way to get rid of this is to `blur()` the target element of the event.

Here's a shotgun/overkill method of how to do this with jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.autoblur').live("click", function(event) {
        this.blur();
    });
});
```